# Order of initialization in Java: exception with Netty 4.0.7

Tags: java, static, netty

I am hitting a problem with Netty at class initialization. I thought static fields are always initialized before instance fields but apparently this is not the case:

- Class AbstractByteBuff contains a `static final ResourceLeakDetector<ByteBuf> leakDetector`
- Class `AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf extends AbstractByteBuff`
- Class `UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf extends AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf`

The first time an UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf is created, a Null Pointer Exception is thrown in its constructor:

```
protected UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ByteBufAllocator alloc, int initialCapacity, int maxCapacity) {
        super(maxCapacity);
        if (alloc == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("alloc");
        }
        if (initialCapacity < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("initialCapacity: " + initialCapacity);
        }
        if (maxCapacity < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("maxCapacity: " + maxCapacity);
        }
        if (initialCapacity > maxCapacity) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(
                    "initialCapacity(%d) > maxCapacity(%d)", initialCapacity, maxCapacity));
        }

        this.alloc = alloc;
        setByteBuffer(ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(initialCapacity));
        leak = leakDetector.open(this);
    }
```

The exception is thrown from the code `leak = leakDetector.open(this);` . By inspecting with intellij Idea I have found out that the `leakDetector` variable is null. How this is possible? It's a static variable initialized in the superclass of the superclass of the current class.

The source code is available on Github, all the classes which raise the problem are available in the following package: https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/buffer/src/main/java/io/netty/buffer

The three sources are the following :

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/buffer/src/main/java/io/netty/buffer/UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/buffer/src/main/java/io/netty/buffer/AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/buffer/src/main/java/io/netty/buffer/AbstractByteBuf.java

This last one, AbstractByteBuff, contains the leakDetector.

Please note I am not compiling the sources but just linking to Netty 4.0.7 final. Here the stackTrace:

```
o.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToByteEncoder.write(MessageToByteEncoder.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:643)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.write(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:633)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:115)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:643)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:689)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:713)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:893)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:239)
    at com.logentries.net.NettyBasedAsyncLogger.logLine(NettyBasedAsyncLogger.java:54)
    at com.logentries.logback.LogentriesAppender.append(LogentriesAppender.java:105)
    at com.logentries.logback.LogentriesAppender.append(LogentriesAppender.java:15)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.AppenderBase.doAppend(AppenderBase.java:85)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:48)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:280)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:267)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:449)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_1(Logger.java:421)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.debug(Logger.java:514)
    at io.netty.util.internal.logging.Slf4JLogger.debug(Slf4JLogger.java:76)
    at io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector.<clinit>(ResourceLeakDetector.java:37)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.<clinit>(AbstractByteBuf.java:37)
    at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(UnpooledByteBufAllocator.java:49)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:132)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:123)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.ioBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:76)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToByteEncoder.write(MessageToByteEncoder.java:107)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:643)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.write(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:633)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:115)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:643)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.access$2000(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:29)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext$WriteTask.run(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:887)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:354)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:366)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.<init>(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:72)
    at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(UnpooledByteBufAllocator.java:49)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:132)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:123)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.ioBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:76)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToByteEncoder.write(MessageToByteEncoder.java:107)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: how is this constructor being invoked?  normal program flow, or part of some other class' static init?

Comment: if that's the case, then something is messed up.  maybe you need to make sure all your classes are recompiled?  can you show the actual exception trace and the `leakDetector` definition?

Comment: what's scary is that if I do a debug / step by step everything works fine. It looks like I am hitting a jvm problem with jdk 1.6u25

Comment: what is the stack trace of the actual exception?

Comment: added stacktrace, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack trace indicates your problem:

```
at io.netty.util.internal.logging.Slf4JLogger.debug(Slf4JLogger.java:76)
at io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector.<clinit>(ResourceLeakDetector.java:37)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.<clinit>(AbstractByteBuf.java:37)
```

`"<clinit>"` means that the classes are in the midst of their class initialization.  it looks like ResourceLeakDetector is generating a log statement during class initialization (before AbstractByteBuf's class init completes and leakDetector is assigned).

UPDATE:

Probably the most confusing part looking at the entire stack trace is that it is not apparent what has *not* happened yet.  The key bit is that the static class initialization of `UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf` *has not yet happened*!  the current status of the jvm is:

1. UnpooledByteBufAllocator is trying to create a new instance of UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf
2. UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf class is loaded (but not initialized)
3. AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf class is loaded (but not initialized) since it is the parent of UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf
4. AbstractByteBuf class is loaded (but not initialized) since it is the parent of AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf
5. AbstractByteBuf class initialization begins (since parents are inited before children), *leakDetector is still null*
6. ResourceLeakDetector class is loaded since it is referenced by AbstractByteBuf class init
7. ResourceLeakDetector class initialization begins, which includes a log statement
8. ...bunch of other method calls are made...
9. UnpooledByteBufAllocator creates a new instance of UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf (this is a recursive call to this method)
10. new instance of UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf is allocated (the class has already been loaded, but not yet initialized)
11. NullPointerException

If you removed the logging call from ResourceLeakDetector class init, what *would* happen is:

1. same
2. same
3. same
4. same
5. same
6. same
7. ResourceLeakDetector class initialization runs to completion
8. AbstractByteBuf class initialization completes, *leakDetector is now assigned*
9. AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf class initialization runs to completion
10. UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf class initialization runs to completion
11. UnpooledByteBufAllocator creates a new instance of UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf
12. life proceeds happily

Comment: I don't agree. I am actually coding a logger, and this might be confusing. But the cause is here: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.<init>(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:72)

Comment: @Edmondo1984 - feel free to disagree all you want, but the answer is right there in the stack trace.  the stack trace is the _exact state_ of the system when the problem occurred.  AbstractByteBuf line 37 is the line where leakDetector is assigned.  since the assignment hasn't happened yet, leakDetector is still null.

Comment: yes, but why it is null if it is a final static member defined on the parent class of the current class?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 - because the parent class has not finished class initialization yet, as you can see from the stack trace.  you have a circular static dependency problem, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416408/static-circular-dependency-in-java

Comment: why it has not ? Can you please detail your answer?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 - detailed

Comment: Awesome ! but why does the log statement produce this effect?

Comment: ouch I got it. My logger was called recursively from netty ... :(